# jquery check a div to see if it has any text in it

Tags: html, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to check if a div has any text in it. if it does then show the div otherwise hide it.

for example:

```
<div id="demo_div"></div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($("#demo_div") has some text) {

    $("#demo_div").show();
    }
    else
   {
   $("#demo_div").hide();
   }
    });
```

which jQuery function should I use to detect if the div has text inside?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First identify the textual content of the div
2. Trim it to remove any trailing white space

```js
let showHide = function($selector)
{
  let text = $selector.text().trim();

  if (text.length > 0)
  {
    console.log("showing", $selector.attr("id"));
    $selector.show();
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("hiding", $selector.attr("id"));

    $selector.hide();
  }
}


showHide($("#demo_div") );
showHide($("#demo_div2") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo_div"> 1</div>

<div id="demo_div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#demo_div").is(':empty')) {
   // Whatever you want to do
}
```

This might solve your problem but remember that line breaks or white spaces are not considered as empty.

For more general case, like you want to remove white spaces and check. In that case you can use trim function along with html method like this

```
if (!$.trim($("#demo_div").html()) {
  // Process
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, is there a way to check if there is any white "space" inside as well?

Comment: Added it in the answer. One suggestion though. If you want to use it at several places, consider creating a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) functions in jquery then check if the returned string is longer than zero. You can optionally [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the result too if you dont want whitespace being considered.

```
<div id="demo_div"></div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if ($("#demo_div").text().trim().length > 0) {
      $("#demo_div").show();
   }
   else
   {
      $("#demo_div").hide();
   }
});
</script>
```

As the name suggest `text()` retrieves textual part of the node while `html()` retrieves everything including html tags. You can choose whichever suits your need.